Cross section profile of: DEM elevation data AND z-values of vector layer vertices
I want a to automate the generation of cross section profiles from elevation from DEM as well as z-values from vector layer vertices and export them as PDF.
The lower part of the images shows the plot as given in QGIS: cross section with vertices z-values and DEM elevation profile. This is exactly what I want to generate.

There is no OutoftheBoxSolution for this as I know so I scripted Python code.
But I encounter problems bringing together DEM elevation profile and the cross section of the vector layer vertices z-values. The plots show weird strings of points instead of a 3 single points for the cross section of the vector lines. Or the plots show the DEM profile properly but the vector points are missing.
So far in my script I used the following elements:

Extract elevation profile from DEM

def get_terrain_profile(geom, dtm_layer, distance, step):
    profile_points = []
    for d in range(-25, 26, int(step * 100)):  
        offset_point = geom.interpolate(distance).asPoint()
        point_on_line = QgsPointXY(offset_point.x() + d, offset_point.y())
        z_value = get_z_value_from_dtm(point_on_line, dtm_layer)
        profile_points.append((d, z_value))  
    return profile_points 


Extract z-values of vertices with QgsPointXY

def extract_elevation_along_profile(querprofilachsen_layer, strassenachse_layer, strassenrand_layer):

    elevation_profiles = []

    for feature in querprofilachsen_layer.getFeatures():
        geometry = feature.geometry()
        
        km_value = feature['km']
        points = []
        step_size = 0.5  
        distance = -25.0  

        intersection_coords = None

        while distance <= 25.0:
            point_on_line = geometry.interpolate(distance + 25.0)  
            
            if point_on_line.isEmpty():
                distance += step_size
                continue
            
            point_as_xy = point_on_line.asPoint()
            relative_x = distance  

            strassenachse_height = get_elevation_from_layer(strassenachse_layer, point_as_xy)
            strassenrand_height = get_elevation_from_layer(strassenrand_layer, point_as_xy)

            points.append((relative_x, strassenachse_height, strassenrand_height))

            if intersection_coords is None and distance == 0:
                intersection_coords = (point_as_xy.x(), point_as_xy.y()) 
            
            distance += step_size

        elevation_profiles.append((km_value, points, intersection_coords))

    return elevation_profiles



Generating Exports with matplotlib

def plot_cross_section(z_values, terrain_profile, distance, pdf):
    terrain_x = [p[0] for p in terrain_profile]  
    terrain_z = [p[1] for p in terrain_profile]  

    x_values = [-12.5, 0, 12.5]
    z_boundary = [z_values[1], z_values[0], z_values[2]] 

    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
    plt.plot(terrain_x, terrain_z, label='Geländeprofil (DTM)', color='black', linestyle='-', linewidth=2) 
    plt.plot(x_values, z_boundary, marker='o', label='Strassenrand', color='red', linestyle='None')
    
    plt.title(f'Querprofil bei {distance} m')
    plt.xlabel('Distanz (m)')
    plt.ylabel('Höhe (m ü.M.)')
    plt.ylim(370, 410)
    plt.xlim(-25, 25)
    plt.axhline(y=0, color='k', linestyle='--')
    plt.grid()
    plt.legend()

I did not use elements like GeoPandas or the like.
I could also not figure out how QGIS internally is rendering the elevation profiles shown on the pictures above.
There are resources to automate generation of DEM cross sections but nothing fits my needs regarding to include z-values from vertices:

Automate Cross Section Profile Extraction from a DEM using Python
Generating series of cross sections (profiles) along line using QGIS
Multiple perpendicular cross sections
Generate multiple profile charts from multiple lines on multiple
DEM
Cross section of the river
Using surveyed cross section of river to create typical cross section for entire river length in ArcGIS Pro

How would a proper Python script look like to bring DEM and vector vertices z-values together on a plot?
Credentials:

Python-Version: 3.9.18
QGIS-Version: 3.36.0-Maidenhead

